# CodeIgniter, check value of a variable by given input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the University ID from my database table. The input comes from the selected option.

**HTML**

```
<li>
<h4>University with cost range</h4>
</li>
<select name="costing">
<option value="1" selected="less than 2 lacs">less than 2 lacs</option>
<option value="2">2 lacs - 4 lacs</option>
<option value="3">4.1 lacs - 6 lacs</option>
<option value="4">6.1 lacs - 8 lacs</option>
<option value="5">8.1 lacs - 10 lacs</option>
<option value="6">More than 10 lacs</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Proceed" />
</form>
```

**Model**

```
   public function university_cost()
{
    $data = $this->input->post('costing');
    if($data == "1")
    {
    $this->db->select('U_ID')->from('cost')->where("Total_cost BETWEEN  00 AND 400000");  
    $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    
    $this->db->select('U_ID, U_Name, Min_result_to_apply')
    ->from('university')
    ->where("U_ID IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();      
    }
      if($data == "2")
    {
    $this->db->select('U_ID')->from('cost')->where("Total_cost BETWEEN  600000 AND 800000");  
    $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    
    $this->db->select('U_ID, U_Name, Min_result_to_apply')
    ->from('university')
    ->where("U_ID IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();      
    }
     
}
```

**Error**

```
<?php foreach($cost as $row1){?>
<tr >
   <td><?php echo `enter code here`$row1['U_ID']?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row1['U_Name']?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $row1['Min_result_to_apply']?></td>
<?php }?>
```

Please help. I have tried several ways, but when I get answer I got it all.. like all the University IDs

**Controller Code**

```
 public function university_by_cost()
    {
        $this->load->model('university_model');
        $data5['cost'] = $this->university_model->university_cost();
        $this->load->view('cost_uni',$data5);
           }
```

**ERROR AT PAGE**

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/cost_uni.php

Comment: Show your controller code and error.

Comment: controller code:       public function university_by_cost()
    {
        $this->load->model('university_model');
        $data5['cost'] = $this->university_model->university_cost();
        $this->load->view('cost_uni',$data5);
           }                                        error msg: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/cost_uni.php

Comment: edit your post and add controller code and error in your post

Comment: try `$data` instead of `$data5`

Comment: tried........nothing happened

Comment: Did you try to print $data5['cost']. what it is giving

Comment: Whats the type of `Total_cost` column in the database table ?

Comment: try <?php foreach($cost->result() as $row1){?>  instead of <?php foreach($cost as $row1){?> in foreach

Comment: if i use this just for test.............       public function university_cost()
        {
            $data = 1;
            if($data == "1")
            {
            $this->db->select('U_ID')->from('cost')->where("Total_cost BETWEEN  00 AND 100000");  
            $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();
            
            $this->db->select('U_ID, U_Name, Min_result_to_apply')
            ->from('university')
            ->where("U_ID IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE);
            return $this->db->get()->result_array();      
            }
            
       }

Comment: but when i send the value by select option tag it causes problems

Comment: whats the problem with $data=$this->input->post("cost");

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the model function by echoing it or print_r() function to see whether an array of requested elements are returned.
In case if nothing is returned check whether $data value or $this->input->post("cost") holds any value or not

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your feedback. I sorted it out. it was a kindda silly mistake that i never wondered. in the HTML section..... it has to be less_than_2_lacs. so, there can be no space. after tried it , i got my problem solved

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have managed to solve my problem